# How to loop through multiple arrays at the same time (parallel)

Tags: php, arrays

Oke so I don't know why this is so hard, all information I find is only for two arrays like array_combine.

I have 3 arrays that I get from dynamically created input fields in a form, so now I want to retrieve the data and print it out like:

```
Item1 (array1)
Item1 (array2)
Item1 (array3)

Item2 (array1)
Item2 (array2)
Item2 (array3)
```

But with my code right now it completes one array and than goes to the next.

```
$article_id = $_REQUEST['article_id'];
$article_descr = $_REQUEST['article_descr'];
$article_ammount = $_REQUEST['article_amount'];

foreach($article_id as $artid) {
    echo = 'Article id: '.$artid.'<br>';
}

foreach($article_descr as $art_descr) {
    echo 'Article description: '.$art_descr.'<br>';
}

foreach($article_ammount as $art_amount) {
    echo 'Article ammount: '.$art_amount.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: if you only want one item per each array, why not just call them directly like `$article_id['item1']` `$article_descr['item1']` ... ?

Comment: do  the arrays relate to each other by their keys?

Comment: Because they are from dynamically added element, so I can't know how many items there are

Comment: @CodeGodie yes the keys relate to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said that all arrays match by their keys, I will assume you have something like this:

```
$article_ids = [10, 22, 13];
$article_descriptions = ["this is one", "this is two", "this is three"];
$article_amounts = [20, 10, 40];
```

Therefore in order to obtain their information in an orderly manner, you would first need to found how many elements there are. We can use the total of the first array, by using `count()`, then using a `for` loop to iterate and obtain each array's information.

```
//get the number of articles
$num = count($article_ids);

//iterate through each article count
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
    echo 'Article id: '.$article_ids[$i].'<br>';
    echo 'Article description: '.$article_descriptions[$i].'<br>';
    echo 'Article amount: '.$article_amounts[$i] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: This can give incorrect result if IDs are not subsequent.

Comment: right, but OP mentioned they do relate to each other.

Comment: related does not means that they are subsequent

Comment: so what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @mitkosoft Then this would work providing you use `array_values` on each array

Comment: I mean that you can have ASSOCIATIVE array such as $article_descr = array(10 => 'item1', 20 => 'item2');

Comment: I see what you mean, but really it depends on what the incoming input is. Good point though.

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie! it is exactly like you describe it

Comment: @Bart You're welcome. Glad I was able to help. If you feel this answer helped you please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that for each item information is under one and the same key in all arrays, you can do following:

```
$article_id = $_REQUEST['article_id'];
$article_descr = $_REQUEST['article_descr'];
$article_ammount = $_REQUEST['article_amount'];

foreach ($article_id as $id => $value) {
    echo 'Article id: ' . $value . '<br>';
    echo 'Article description: ' . $article_descr[$id] . '<br>';
    echo 'Article ammount: ' . $article_ammount[$id] . '<br>';
}
```